# Regex for Google Analytics Goals

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've searched all the other Regex on Google Analytics questions but I can't use the answers as this is pretty specific to my problem.

I want to set a goal but use Regex to flag it as a goal IF string includes

> /client-thank-you/ AND anything EXCEPT hire

so in other words

> /client-thank-you/hire is not correct
>
> /client-thank-you/anything/else is correct

Comment: One alternative would be to include the paths that you know would be part of a conversion, and then just `or` them together: `/client-thank-you/(include|all|the|possible|paths)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the following regexes will match any string that contains `/client-thank-you/` and does not contain `hire`, depending on what assumption(s) you make about where "hire" is in the string.

---

## Solution

*Where can "hire" be located in the string?*

**Anywhere:**

```regex
((?!hire).)*?/client-thank-you/((?!hire).)*
```

**Only following the "/client-thank-you/":**

```regex
.*?/client-thank-you/((?!hire).)*
```

**Only immediately following the "/client-thank-you/":**

```regex
.*?/client-thank-you/(?!hire).*
```

---

## Notes

**Optimization:**

Each of these regexes will match the entire string.  If your tool lets you determine if a string contains a substring match (rather than naively attempting to match the entire string), then you could optimize the second and third regexes by removing the leading `.*?`.  Likewise, the third regex could be further optimized by removing the trailing `.*` as well.

**Positively require "anything":**

Note that all of these regexes assume that a string that ends with "/client-thank-you/" (with nothing after it) is valid.  If this assumption is incorrect (i.e. the string `.*/client-thank-you/$` is not a match), then change the trailing `*` on every regex to `+`.  This would also mean that you have to keep the last `.*` on the third regex as a `.+` (i.e. don't optimize that away).

---

---

## EDIT:

The above will not work since GA uses a very limited version of regex (that does not include lookaround).  If there is no other GA tool (other than a single regex) that you can use that meets your needs, then you could use the following as a last-ditch effort:

```regex
([-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-gi-z]|h[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-hj-z]|hi[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-qs-z]|hir[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-df-z]|.{1,3}$)
```

And in expanded form for illustration purposes only:

```regex
(                                |                                 |                                  |                                   |       )
 [-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-gi-z] h[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-hj-z] hi[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-qs-z] hir[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-df-z] .{1,3}$
```

This regex will match 1-4 characters that do not form "hire".  It does so by matching the minimum number of characters necessary to verify that the match is neither "hire" nor can serve as a prefix of "hire".  It takes into account end-of-line (e.g. "hir" is valid if there is nothing else after it).  The characters that it matches are all valid characters that can occur in the path component of a URL as specified in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

You use this regex by substituting it for every `((?!hire).)` in any of the solutions given above.  For example:

```regex
.*?/client-thank-you/([-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-gi-z]|h[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-hj-z]|hi[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-qs-z]|hir[-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/0-9A-Za-df-z]|.{1,3}$).*
```

This matches any url that contains "/client-thank-you/" but not "/client-thank-you/hire".

Do be careful, though.  Doubled "h"s will make this workaround fail (e.g. "hhire").  However, if "hire" will only ever follow a path delimiter (i.e. `/hire/`), then that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This unfortunately won't work with GA, as GA uses a different regex engine that does not (officially) include lookaheads.

Comment: @nyuen Blast... Does GA allow regex-based filters to be nested / chained?  Something like `include if contains "/client-thank-you/"` then `exclude if contains "hire"`?

Comment: @travis thanks a lot for your reply but as Nyuen pointed out that did not work. Annoying. Any other ideas I can test

Comment: @JPStones See my previous comment.  Does GA allow you to nest / chain / pipe filters?

Comment: hey, these are the filters you are allowed


Wildcard Meaning
. match any single character
* match zero or more of the previous item
+ match one or more of the previous item
? match zero or one of the previous item
() remember contents of parenthesis as item
[] match one item in this list
- create a range in a list
| or
^ match to the beginning of the field
$ match to the end of the field
\ escape any of the above

Comment: not sure if i have to tag @travis in the above post. Thanks again for your help though

Comment: thanks @travis I tested if these gave results and found that they seem to work. so properly testing now. Thanks so much for your time. really really appreciate it. And i had no idea regex could look so confusing!

Comment: @JPStones Glad I could help! And normally regex doesn't look so confusing... it just is in this case because it's workaround rather than a proper regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a lookahead like Travis suggested, then I suggest setting the goal to fire on an event instead of a pageview.

If you're using Google Tag Manager, you'll have the ability to write a more advanced regex, or at least set a blocking rule for the event that prevents it from firing when 'hire' is in the page URL.